# React Native Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm getting the error:

[image]

It's funny because I don't setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. I just set state on the Input or Picker onChange methods.

```
class AddWorkOrder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedUnit: undefined,
      selectedPriority: undefined,
      selectedVendor: undefined,
      selectedAssigned: undefined,
      descValue: '',
      CommonArea: false,
      photo: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAsyncUnits();
    this.getAsyncVendors();
    this.getAsyncPriorities();
    this.getAsyncAssigned();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.status !== this.props.status) {
      this.getUnitsAsync();
    }
  }

  onChangeUnit(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selectedUnit: value
    });
  }

  onChangePriority(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selectedPriority: value
    });
  }

  onChangeVendor(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selectedVendor: value
    });
  }

  onChangeAssigned(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selectedAssigned: value
    });
  }

  getAsyncUnits = async () => { await this.props.getUnits(); };
  getAsyncVendors = async () => { await this.props.getVendors(); };
  getAsyncPriorities = async () => { await this.props.getPriorities(); };
  getAsyncAssigned = async () => { await this.props.getAssigned(); };

  saveWK() {
    if (this.state.selectedUnit === undefined) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Unit is required!');
      return;
    }
    if (this.state.descValue === '') {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Description is required!');
      return;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { units, vendors, wkpriorities, assignedList } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Form>
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Octicons active name="tools" size={18} />
              <Text style={styles.cardText}>   Add Work Order</Text>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
          <Item picker>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select Unit"
              placeholder="Units"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedUnit}
              onValueChange={this.onChangeUnit.bind(this)}
            >
            {Object.keys(units).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={units[key]}
                    value={key}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
            })}
            </Picker>
          </Item>
          <Item picker>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select Priority"
              placeholder="Priority"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedPriority}
              onValueChange={this.onChangePriority.bind(this)}
            >
            {Object.keys(wkpriorities).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={wkpriorities[key]}
                    value={key}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
            })}
            </Picker>
          </Item>

          <Item picker>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select Assigned To"
              placeholder="Assigned To"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedAssigned}
              onValueChange={this.onChangeAssigned.bind(this)}
            >
            {Object.keys(assignedList).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={assignedList[key]}
                    value={key}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
            })}
            </Picker>
          </Item>

          <Item picker>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              iosHeader="Select Vendor"
              placeholder="Vendor"
              iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
              style={{ width: undefined }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedVendor}
              onValueChange={this.onChangeVendor.bind(this)}
            >
            {Object.keys(vendors).map((key) => {
                return (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={vendors[key]}
                    value={key}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
            })}
            </Picker>
          </Item>

          <Item>
            <Input
              placeholder='Description'
              placeholderTextColor="#C0C0C0"
              value={this.state.descValue}
              onChangeText={(descValue) => this.setState({ descValue })}
              multiline
              style={{ height: 100 }}
            />
          </Item>

          <ListItem>
            <CheckBox
              checked={this.state.CommonArea} color="blue"
              onPress={() => this.setState({ CommonArea: !this.state.CommonArea })}
            />
            <Body>
              <Text>  Common Area?</Text>
            </Body>
          </ListItem>
          <Button
            full
            onPress={() => this.saveWK()}
          >
            <Text>Save</Text>
          </Button>

        </Form>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea where this loop is being triggered? From the error it looks like is from the Picker, but I can't find the reason of the issue.

Thanks

Adding my Action:

```
...

export const getUnits = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        "1": "101",
        "2": "102",
        "3": "103",
        "4": "104",
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_UNITS,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};

export const getVendors = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        "1": "Vendor1",
        "2": "Vendor2",
        "3": "Vendor3",
        "4": "Vendor4",
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_VENDORS,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};

export const getPriorities = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        '1': 'High',
        '3': 'Low',
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_WO_PRIORITY,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};

export const getAssigned = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const units = {
        '1': 'Maintenance 1',
        '2': 'Maintenance 2',
        '3': 'Maintenance 3',
    };
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ASSIGNED_LIST,
      payload: units
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: what does getUnitsAsync do

Comment: Sorry, it is my action methods. I just added it.

Comment: If I remove all the Pickers components, it works

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't share, I don't know what this.getUnitsAsync() does.  However, because this function does not change the state value, then it falls into an infinite loop. You can avoid an infinite loop only if you change your conditions correctly or modify the function.

Comment: Sorry, it is my action methods. I just added it.

Comment: I can't see the function getUnitsAsync on the list I added. Where is this function?